# Why isn't if [ sudo docker ps | ... ] valid syntax in bash?

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to learn `awk`. I want to do a `sudo docker ps` and if the first element of the second column of the second line is `x` then it prints `ok`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ sudo docker ps | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}' = "portainer/agent" ]
then
     echo "Sucess"
else
     echo "Error"
fi
```

questions:

Is this the way that we parse commands into awk? (`docker ps | awk` )?
The outputs says command not found.

I think i'm messing some bash fundamentals somewhere...

Or should I do

```
sudo docker ps
if [ awk 'FNR == " {print $2}' = "portainer" ]
then
    echo "sucess"
else
    echo "error"
```

Comment: But when you say `x`, you mean the string `portainer/agent`?

Comment: yes! sorry, should have specified

Comment: As William mentioned below, seems unwise to assume what you want will be on line 2 of the output. Why not just search the output for lines with the relevant string instead of specifying a line number? `awk` can use either... For that matter, I'd do my test and print in `awk` here too, though if you need it from `bash` you can arrange it that way...

Comment: Please post a couple of sample outputs from `sudo docker ps`, one for _sucess_ and one for _error_.

Comment: the print of docker ps, in my case, WILL ALLWAYS be the same, since i only have 1 container running at any and all times, i know theres better ways to do it, but then again i am doing this simply to learn awk, not to actually deploy something :)
the only case it would not be same is it the container was not running, in that case the "docker ps" only return an empty second line

Comment: It's valid *shell* syntax; the problem is that the `test` command, when invoked as `[`, requires its last argument to be `]`. `[` is *not* just a grouping operator, despite its apparent intention to look like one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not addressing the wisdom of specifying row 2 of the output of `docker ps` (is that a stable interface?), but the syntax you're looking for is (possibly, there are many options!):

```
#!/bin/bash
if sudo docker ps | awk 'FNR == 2 && $2 == "portainer/agent" {s=1} END {exit !s}'
then
     echo "Success"
else
     echo "Error" >&2
fi
```

A few things to note: don't bother with the `[` command.  Instead, just evaluate the return status of awk.  `awk` returns `!s` because success in the shell is indicated by a zero status; the variable `s` will have a value of zero unless the condition is satisfied, so we invert it before returning to the shell.  Note that "Error" is written to stderr.  Error messages need to go to the right place.

Another option (which I really advise against, but many people do things this way, so it's good to know the syntax) is to check the output of awk with something like:

```
if test "$(sudo docker ps | awk 'FNR == 2 && $2 == "portainer/agent" {print "ok"}
    ')" = ok; then ...
```

Note that I'm using `test` instead of `[`.  They are the same thing except that `test` does not require its final argument to be `]`, and I think shell scripts are far less confusing when the reader doesn't get tempted to think that `[` is part of the grammar and is some sort of operator.  But that is completely a stylistic choice.  Some would argue that you should never use `[` or `test` and instead use `[[` (which is part of the grammar).  YMMV

Here, note the quoting. It is not necessary to quote the raw string `ok`, since it is not subject to word splitting, although many style guides (rightfully) recommend that it be quoted.  I leave it unquoted here to emphasize the next point.  It *is* required to quote the output of the process substitution, because if awk prints nothing you want to pass the empty string as a parameter to `test`.  If there were no quotes, then the first argument passed to `test` would be `=`, which would generate an error.  In general, the purpose of double quotes is to protect against word splitting and to define empty strings.  This isn't particularly relevant to your question, though, and deserves a more lengthy treatment than these comments.

Comment: thanks a lot! now i get it! sorry for the noobish questions, i did the classical error of wenting to google and just paste stuff without rly knowing what was going on.
i will accept your question! just need to wait 2 more minutes.
again, thank you so much.
also, yes docker ps, prints a pretty list of the docker processes running.